# How to cluster markers using the “Geojson-dashboard” in Leaflet JavaScript

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, markers

I know how to use Leaflet.markercluster, but for some reason I can't use with geojson-dashboard framework template for Leaflet (http://fulcrumapp.github.io/geojson-dashboard/).

But I have a simple problem, I'd like to cluster the points but maintain all the setting, I've already tried so many options but until now I couldn't.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell a little bit more about "I can't use" and "I couldn't"?

Comment: Table stop syncing with the table?

Comment: the markers in the map stop syncing with table when I cluster the markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin is added to framework template http://fulcrumapp.github.io/geojson-dashboard/, it doesn't work because this example uses old version of Leaflet (0.7).

If newer version (1.4.0) of Leaflet is used, original code has to be modified at two places to make it work as it is (without marker clusters):

```
// ESRI geocoder
// before: var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.Controls.geosearch({
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
  useMapBounds: 17
}).addTo(map);

function syncTable() {
  tableFeatures = [];
  featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.feature.properties.leaflet_stamp = L.stamp(layer);
    if (map.hasLayer(featureLayer)) {
// before: if (map.getBounds().contains(layer.getBounds())) {
      if (map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())) {
        tableFeatures.push(layer.feature.properties);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#table").bootstrapTable("load", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableFeatures)));
  var featureCount = $("#table").bootstrapTable("getData").length;
  if (featureCount == 1) {
    $("#feature-count").html($("#table").bootstrapTable("getData").length + " visible feature");
  } else {
    $("#feature-count").html($("#table").bootstrapTable("getData").length + " visible features");
  }
}
```

To add marker clusters, `L.geoJson` layer `featureLayer` is renamed to `featureLayerUngrouped` and used only for creating markers and adding them to newly created `L.markerClusterGroup` layer named `featureLayer`. This is the changed part of the code:

```
// new cluster group
var featureLayer = L.markerClusterGroup({
  maxClusterRadius: 30
});

// old renamed geoJson feature group used for loading markers
var featureLayerUngrouped = L.geoJson(null, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return feature.geometry.coordinates[0] !== 0 && feature.geometry.coordinates[1] !== 0;
  },
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties["marker-color"]) {
      markerColor = feature.properties["marker-color"];
    } else {
      markerColor = "#FF0000";
    }
    var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 4,
      weight: 2,
      fillColor: markerColor,
      color: markerColor,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1
    });
    // marker added to cluster group
    featureLayer.addLayer(marker);
    return marker;
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
      layer.on({
        click: function (e) {
          identifyFeature(L.stamp(layer));
          highlightLayer.clearLayers();
          highlightLayer.addData(featureLayer.getLayer(L.stamp(layer)).toGeoJSON());
        },
        mouseover: function (e) {
          if (config.hoverProperty) {
            $(".info-control").html(feature.properties[config.hoverProperty]);
            $(".info-control").show();
          }
        },
        mouseout: function (e) {
          $(".info-control").hide();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

// Fetch the GeoJSON file
$.getJSON(config.geojson, function (data) {
  geojson = data;
  features = $.map(geojson.features, function(feature) {
    return feature.properties;
  });
  // data loaded to geoJson feature group
  featureLayerUngrouped.addData(data);
  buildConfig();
  $("#loading-mask").hide();
});
```

**EDIT**: Function `applyFilter()` also has to be modified:

```
function applyFilter() {
  var query = "SELECT * FROM ?";
  var sql = $("#query-builder").queryBuilder("getSQL", false, false).sql;
  if (sql.length > 0) {
    query += " WHERE " + sql;
  }
  alasql(query, [geojson.features], function(features){
    featureLayer.clearLayers();
//  added
    featureLayerUngrouped.clearLayers();
//  before: featureLayer.addData(features);
    featureLayerUngrouped.addData(features);
    syncTable();
  });
}
```

With this cluster markers are working.

It's interesting that it doesn't work with latest version of Leaflet (1.5.1). I didn't investigate furter to find the reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot about your answer, the cluster markers really work now, but the filter stop working, could you give me a hand?

Comment: Quite some time went into above solution and it solved your problem. If you show some appreciation, I might consider further investigation.

Comment: Hi TomazicM, you help me a lot with your answer, you can't imagine, because I've already tried in so many differents ways withou sucess, but only the filter stop working. I'm new user here, I'm learning how to use this community and I'd like to how can I help you too.

Comment: Simply uptick the answer as a sign that it was useful to you.

Comment: Ok, you help me again, I apreciate it.

Comment: Added modification for `applyFilter()` function, so filter should work now.

Comment: if I had I'll give you one million dollars, thanks a lot. It's very usefull.